# Insert text into label/image using Qt - C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

yes I already searched stackoverflow and implemented at least 3 out 5 things that i saw, with no success. I'm new to C++, tried to learn with SoloLearn but there you got only the basics.

I'm trying to develop an OpenSource software to create e-mail signatures in batch, and, export those signatures in all sorts of formats possible.

Till now, I'm able to search onto Windows for the background image, display it as a preview, but, i'm not able to insert any text in the image. Here is what my code looks like:

```
void CriaAssinaturas::on_selecionarImagemDeFundo_clicked()
    {
        QString filter = "All Files (*.*) ;; JPEG File (*.jpeg) ;; BMP File (*.bmp)";
        QString file_name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Carregar uma imagem", QDir::homePath(), filter) ;
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Arquivo selecionado:", file_name);
        QFile file(file_name);
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        QPixmap previaAssinatura(file_name);
        ui->exemploAssinatura->setPixmap(previaAssinatura);
}
//    QString nome = ui->nomeInput->text();
//    ui->showNome->setText(nome);

//    QPainter pintaNome;
//    pintaNome.drawText(630,170,"Print something");

void CriaAssinaturas::on_salvarAssinatura_clicked()
{
//  ui->exemploAssinatura->grab().save("fileName.jpg");
    QString file_name = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Salvar uma imagem", QDir::homePath());
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Arquivo salvo em QDir::homePath()", file_name);

}

void CriaAssinaturas::on_criarAssinatura_clicked()
{
    QString txt = ui->nomeInput->text();
    ui->showNome->setText(txt);
}
```

Comment: you can use a QPainter on the qpixmap, with [drawtext](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawText)

Comment: What is the QLabel?

Comment: ui->showNome->setText(txt); being showNome my Qlabel.

Comment: Already tried the Qpainter using:  //    QPainter pintaNome;
//    pintaNome.drawText(630,170,"Print something goddamnit");

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a pixmap already set on the `ui->exemploAssinatura` and `ui->showNome` is the *QLabel* you want to show the overlayed text in, in `on_criarAssinatura_clicked()` try this:

```
QPixmap pixmap(ui->exemploAssinatura->pixmap());
QPainter pintaNome(&pixmap);

pintaNome.drawText(630, 170, ui->nomeInput->text());
ui->showNome->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

Check out [QPainter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) and [QFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html) for ideas of how to add some artistic effects to the text.

Comment: change  `QPixmap pixmap(*ui->exemploAssinatura->pixmap());` to `QPixmap pixmap(ui->exemploAssinatura->pixmap());`

Comment: @eyllanesc, was a typo. Thank you!